# Formatting a ratio as a percentage in Clojure

Tags: clojure, string-formatting

This seems like it should be obvious, but how do you convert Clojure's ratio type to a percentage?

```
(format "%3s" (/ 1 2))
;; "1/2"

(format "%3f" (/ 1 2))
;; Throws an error
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always convert to `Float`:

```
(format "%3f" (float (/ 1 2)))
```

Comment: Or you can use `double`.

Answer (score 5):

[`cl-format`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/cl-format), which is derived from Common Lisp's [`format`](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html), is more flexible than Clojure's Java-based `format` in some situations:

```
(require 'clojure.pprint)
(clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~f" (/ 1 2)) ;=> "0.5"
```

Answer (score 4):

Should've read the source:

```
(.decimalValue (/ 1 2))
```

does what I needed.